# How to smooth out the android compas sensor

Tags: android

I am working on a semi augmented reality app where smooth and accurate data is very important. the sensors return values that jump around between 0 and 4 degrees and unfortunately it is making life difficult.

i have tried implementing a temporary solution:

```
private float[] Total = new float[11];
private float Average(){
    if (counter == Total.length - 1) {
        counter --;
        for (int i = 0; i < Total.length - 1; i++) {
            Total[i] = Total[i + 1];
        }
    }
    float tot = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Total.length - 1; i++) {
        tot = tot + Total[i];
    }
    return tot/counter;
}
```

but this does not meet my needs any advice or help?

Comment: I think there is accuracy for each sensor, read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-monitor

Answer (score 0):

You are using a moving mean filter in a [FIR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response) implementation. In spite of its simplicity, the moving average filter is optimal for a common task: reducing random noise while retaining a sharp step response.

A disadvantage of the FIR implementation is that the computation time increases with the size of the filter. You could look into implementing the filter in a [IIR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_impulse_response) filter instead but for this simple application I would not recommend it.

Another improvement might be to use a [window function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) to minimize edge effects.

You may find a good example of a low pass filter using a Hamming window [here](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/cag/streamit/results/fm/code/streamit/LowPassFilter.java)

Comment: I only finished school now and read up on those filters you mentioned. I am having trouble understanding how it would be implemented because currently the Float array i am using gets flooded with the new data consistently so it is working on the iir unless i am understanding it wrong. I would appreciate it if you could help me in an easier way or maybe with an example :) ty

Comment: I'm writing an example for you :)

Comment: i see why you said it is not recommended. it would take a lot of processing power to add this into my application. fortunately the window function gave me an idea to throw away the abnormal readings and reduce the range at which it needs to find the average.

Comment: Yes, convolution is rather processor intensive but as I gather that the readings from the magnetometer is not that frequent (a few times/s) I would not rule out the filter because of that.